# jQuery Validate, but only after initial submission

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the very nice bassistance validation plugin for all my form validation needs:
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

A problem I encounter: error messages appear instantly, even when a user hasn't finished completing a field. As such: invalid e-mail appears until the user has finished typing.

In the documentation [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), one solution is to set the option `onkeyup` to `false` causing error messages to only appear onblur.

However, in **my setup**, I encounter two additional issues (not solved by the solution above)

1. Upon submitting an invalid form, error messages are not cleared when correcting them
2. When the browser autofill function used, automatically filled out fields stay marked as erroneous.

So, my initial question was: how can I make Bassistance validation fire only after the first submit AND with it's default settings from there on out?

Here's my code:

```
if($('#contact_form').length) {
    $("#contact_form").validate({
        rules: {
            first_name: {
                required: true
            },
            last_name: {
                required: true
            },
            message: {
                required: true
            },
            telephone: {
                required: true
            },              
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            email_again: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                equalTo: "#email"
            },
            norobot: {
                required:true,
                minlength:4,
                maxlength:4,
                number:true     
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Please find the full JavaScript here: http://lad.chocolata.be/js/main.js

Here is a working example with bug with `onkeyup` set to `false`:
http://lad.chocolata.be/nl/contact

After submitting the form with some invalid fields, the error messages do not clear upon correcting them.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please include your code within the original posting so we can get this re-opened.

Comment: Hi, I humbly disagree with the closing of my question. The code is too large to post in its entirety here, that's why I have included links to both examples. I've tried reproducing this behaviour in JSFiddle, but cannot. I'm guessing there's a conflict between some of my scripts. Could you kindly have a look at the provided links? Try submitting the form without filling out anything, then correct the fields: you will see that the errors are not cleared. In the mean time, I will rewrite this question to be more clear.

Comment: The whole idea of this site also includes helping future readers, which can't happen when external links go dead.  Anything you can do to create a concise example would be instrumental towards getting it re-opened.  Even simply taking my simple jsFiddle and splitting it into your two cases would be better.

Comment: Like this [default example](http://jsfiddle.net/WzcWg/) and this [example with events disabled](http://jsfiddle.net/Jt8bC/).

Comment: I understand and agree. The problem is that I cannot reproduce this behaviour in JSFiddle: it is specific to my setup apparently. I've updated and clarified the question. Could you please have another look?

Comment: I voted to re-open.  You may also flag it to have a moderator re-open.  Make note that the accepted answer may also help make the whole thing more clear.

Comment: The other part of the question is now solved aswell. This was a CSS issue. I declared `.form label.error { display: block !important; clear: both; }` which causes problems after the first submit.

Comment: Yeah, that `display:block;` needs to be over-written by the plugin and when you use `!important`, that's not going to allow it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Quote OP:**  *"So, plain and simple, my question is: how can I make Bassistance validation fire only after the first submit AND with it's
>   default settings from there on out?"*

**Warning to the reader:**  Normally, one would call `.validate()` *once* on DOM ready to initialize the form.  The code below only calls `.validate()` *once* when the submit button is initially pressed... therefore, there will be **no** validation whatsoever until that button is pressed the first time.

There is no need to call `.validate()` more than once, so I used the [jQuery `one()` event](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#submit').one('click', function() {
        $('#myform').validate({
            // your rules & options
        });
    });

});
```

**Working Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/hSDyP/

Comment: Excellent answer, Sparky. One question: I've tried clicking the submit button, and tried pressing enter: both cases work. Do we have all possible situations covered then? Or would it be better to use the event handler onsubmit?

Comment: @maartenmachiels, Assuming JS is enabled, then I'd say "yes", you're covered.  I'd avoid anything that uses the `submit` event since that's already handled by the plugin's own `submitHandler`.  In other words, you're not really `submit`'ting at that point quite yet, so there's no reason to use that event.

Comment: The winner takes it all then :-) Thanks for your excellent contributions. Much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a generic solution to avoid applying valitation until first submit occurs. Just use  this code after including your script 'jquery.validate.js' :

```
(function($){

var _validate = $.fn.validate;

$.fn.validate = function(){
    var result, args = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);
    this.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            lazyValidate = $this.data('lazy-validate');
        // Lazy validation has been initialized: just delegate
        if( lazyValidate === true ){
            result = _validate.apply($this, args);
            return;
        }
        // Init, if not yet
        if( !lazyValidate ){
            // Create Lazy Form 
            lazyValidate = $('<form />')[0];
            $this.data('lazy-validate', lazyValidate);
            // Add One-Time submit handlder
            $this.one('submit.lazy-validate', function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                // Apply validation options now
                _validate.call($this, $(lazyValidate).data('validator').settings);
                // Mark lazy validation has initialized
                $this.data('lazy-validate', true);
                // Test Valid
                return $this.valid();
            });
        }
        // Apply Method to Lazy Form
        result = _validate.apply($(lazyValidate), args);
    });
    return result === undefined ? this : result;        
};  

})(jQuery);
```

Keep in mind that solution would not work if you are using field's methods: rules(), removeAttrs().

Finally, I think this functionality should be included in the valation plugin as a simple validate() option; but until that I'll still using this trick.

Comment: That's pretty verbose, IMO.  What's the advantage over the accepted answer?